# Reset the GUI to initial state with a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In this code, the "Change Input Option" button switches between "Process" and "Browse" button. If we press any one of them, the buttons below it get activated. When "Change Input Option" button is clicked again, I want it to disable the buttons below "Process" and "Browse" and start switching between "Process" and "Browse" button again as it did initially. How do I do that?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
window = tk.Tk()

def browse_file1():

    if browse_button["state"] == "normal":
        show_fig["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        show_fig["state"] = "normal" 

def open_window():   
    if submit_button["state"] == "disabled":

        save_button["state"] = "disabled"
        show_button["state"] = "disabled"

    else:
        save_button["state"] = "normal"       
        show_button["state"] = "normal"   

def switch1():
    submit_button.state(('!disabled' if 'disabled' in submit_button.state() else 'disabled',))
    browse_button.state(('!disabled' if 'disabled' in browse_button.state() else 'disabled',))

window.configure(background='white')
ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 700 # width for the Tk root
h = 410  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))      
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,bg="white",width=700, height=410, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

submit_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Process", command=lambda: open_window())
canvas.create_window(560, 215, window=submit_button, anchor=tk.NW)

show_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text='Show Figure')
canvas.create_window(523, 248, window=show_button, anchor=tk.NW)

save_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Save Entry")
canvas.create_window(605, 248, window=save_button, anchor=tk.NW)

browse_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text='Browse', command= lambda: browse_file1())
canvas.create_window(150, 335, window=browse_button, anchor=tk.NW)

show_fig = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Show Figure")
canvas.create_window(150, 370, window=show_fig, anchor=tk.NW)

show_fig["state"] = "disabled"
browse_button["state"] = "disabled"

save_button["state"] = "disabled"
show_button["state"] = "disabled"

one_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text='Change Input Option', command=switch1)
canvas.create_window(17, 13, window=one_button, anchor=tk.NW)  

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
    if str(submit_button["state"]) == "disabled":
        submit_button["state"] = "normal"
        browse_button["state"] = "disabled"
        show_fig["state"] = "disabled"

    elif str(browse_button["state"]) == "disabled":
        submit_button["state"] = "disabled"
        browse_button["state"] = "normal"
        save_button["state"] = "disabled"
        show_button["state"] = "disabled"
```

Just replace your `switch1()` function with this.